Is there a way to prevent the usage of *ngIf in favor of @if
Angular introduced the control flow blocks in v17 (@if, @for, @switch, etc.)
We migrated the entirety of our application to this new syntax and we are now wondering if there is any integrated option in Angular to prevent the use of *ngIf and only allow the use of the new syntax exclusively ?
Or should we adapt our linter configuration with a custom rule ?
Searched for an existing option online or an alternative without success.

The best way to do it is through linter.
Angular 17.1.0 provides exactly that.
You can add the rule @angular-eslint/template/prefer-control-flow to your eslint configuration.

This answer is getting traction it seems. So I'd just like to chip in that there is a migration script available to can convert from directives to control-flow, just do
ng generate @angular/core:control-flow

Angular doesn't provide a built-in way to enforce the exclusive use of the new control flow syntax and prevent the use of *ngIf. To achieve this, you could use the @angular-eslint/template/prefer-control-flow rule, which has been available in angular-eslint since v17.1.0 
For More information
